# Is it correct ? Help me if you know 

Tags: grammar

I want to post a picture with my brother that both of us wear black , is this caption correct ? "Siblings in black" , we should use siblings or sibling ?

Comment: One brother only

Comment: No, there is *not* only one brother in the picture. Think.

Answer (score 1):

How many siblings are in the picture? If the answer is "more than one" then you should use the plural form.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey But the OP may be female!